# Generate RSA Key in Azure KeyVault using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I want to create RSA Key in Azure Key Vault using ARM template

All what I found is a REST API to do it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/createkey/createkey any ideas if this applicable through ARM template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, its not, unfortunately. Only "things" exposed to ARM are keyvault resources, secrets and accessPolicies:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/allversions

update:

possible now.

```
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', parameters('keyName'))]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
            "properties": {
                "attributes": "[parameters('attributes')]",
                "crv": "[parameters('crv')]",
                "kty": "[parameters('kty')]",
                "key_ops": "[parameters('key_ops')]",
                "key_size": "[parameters('key_size')]"
            }
        }
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/modules/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/0.9/azuredeploy.json

Comment: Thanks, any idea if it has commands through powershell or Azure CLI or I will just need to call the REST API from powershell ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-key-create this looks like the cmd you are looking for

Comment: This is not correct according to the MS documentation - they even provide a sample template that can be used to generate a key: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/modules/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/0.9